# How can I destroy a fragment (or a view)?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have created this fragment:

```
var dialogFrafment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
    "appIntra.fragment.dialog",
    this.getView().getController() // associate controller with the fragment            
);
this.getView().addDependent(dialogFrafment);
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idMailReport").setValue(sap.ui.getCore().getModel("mailUser"));

dialogFrafment.
dialogFrafment.open();
```

How can I delete it after it is complete?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to delete it?

Comment: Since fragments only return the Control that gets returned in createContent of your fragment you can destroy it like every other UI5 Control using .destroy()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store your dialogFrafment in your controller.

```java
if(!this.dialogFrafment) {
    this.dialogFrafment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
        "appIntra.fragment.dialog",
        this.getView().getController() // associate controller with the fragment            
    );
    this.getView().addDependent(dialogFrafment);
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("idMailReport").setValue(sap.ui.getCore().getModel("mailUser"));
}  
this.dialogFrafment.open();
```

Destroy the fragment in onExit function of your controller.

```java
onExit: function() {
    if (this.dialogFrafment) {
        this.dialogFrafment.destroy(true);
    }

},
```

Comment: and how can I do it if i instantiate xml into onInit? How Can I retrieve it?
Store  dialogFrafment in my controller don't work by `this.`.